# Grand Total Cross Tab rows alongwith columns?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I want to total a cross tab report like

```
GroupName  Items    Item% 1stStock 2ndStock  ------ nStock
---------  -----   ------ -------- --------         ------- 
 Fruits    Apples     5       100    100             500
           Tomatoes   10      200     50             200
           Mangoes    10      300     50             100
------------------------------------------------------------ 
 Total                25%     600    200              800 
------------------------------------------------------------
 Vegetables Carrots   40      10      20    ---------  20
 ------------------------------------------------------------ 
 Total                40%     10      20    ---------  20  
------------------------------------------------------------
 GrandTotal           65%     610    20               820
```

How do I make sub totals and grand totals for the rows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of these should work for you:

Manual Method:

1. Group your report by GroupName
2. Drag & drop your fields onto the details section.
3. On each of your numeric fields, **right click->insert->summary** (turn on "add to all group levels" to create both a subtotal and a grandtotal)

Crystal's Crosstab Method:

1. Make a blank crosstab in your report header.
2. In the Crosstab Expert, define your Rows as {GroupName} and {Items}.
3. For Summarized Fields, sum your {nStock} fields.
4. Leave the Crosstab Expert and **right click->Row Grand Totals->Totals on Top** to put the subtotals below the individual values.