# Average of two columns in crystal report using crosstab

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010, crosstab

I cant get the right Sub Total and Total of this formula

Output is

[image]

Formula is `((collections / collectibles) * 100)`

Is there a way to change the formula of Sub total and of a column?

I'm using crystal report in vb.net windows application program

Answer (score 0):

This is for simple detail section

1. Create a "Formula Field" (Not a running total field) called Total
2. In the Formula Editor grab "Functions" (Middle divider) -> Summary -> Sum -> Sum(fld) and put it in the editor portion
3. Drag the "Amounts" that you want the total of and and put it in the Sum function
4. Put this formula field in the footer (It should display the total I believe you want)

Please check this link.

https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/614/running-total-field-in-crystal-report

http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1117914-subtotals-by-page

**Edit**
If you using cross-tab, then its very easy. Cross-tab given row wise, column wise total and grand -total too.

check this links.

[Grand Total Cross Tab rows alongwith columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582395/grand-total-cross-tab-rows-alongwith-columns)

[Add "Total" per row and column in Crystal Reports without CrossTab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567625/add-total-per-row-and-column-in-crystal-reports-without-crosstab)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm using crosstab. I cant use the detail section